# what does a comma do in the first parameter of a for loop?

Tags: php, for-loop

What does it mean when there is a comma in the first parameter of a [for loop](http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.for.php)?

For example:

```
for ($j=0, $n2=sizeof($quotes[$i]['methods']); $j<$n2; $j++) {
    //
}
```

Comment: It's declaring more than one variable. In this instance `$j` and `$n2`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`PHP` inherited `C++`-like syntax.

It is common for `C++`-like languages to have scope visibility for code blocks or control structures, like:

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main() {

    int a = 0; // main scope;
    int b = 5; // main scope;

    if(a != b){
        int c = a + b; // if scope;
        // a, b, c visible.
    }

    // a and b visible, but c - not visible.

    for(int i = 10; i < 20; i++){
        // for-loop scope:
        // i, a and b visible

        cout << "i: " << i << endl;
    }

    // a and b visible, but i - not visible.

    return 0;
}
```

PHP has no such feature, but inherited syntax rules (and most of `C++` code conventions).

```
<?php
header('Content-Type: text/plain');

for($i = 0, $j = 10; $i < 10; $i++, $j += 2){
    echo "{$i} + {$j} = ", $i + $j, PHP_EOL;
}
?>
```

is equival to

```
<?php
header('Content-Type: text/plain');

$j = 10;

for($i = 0; $i < 10; $i++){
    echo "{$i} + {$j} = ", $i + $j, PHP_EOL;

    $j += 2;
}
?>
```

Variables `$i` and `$j` will be accessible everywhere after `for`-loop, but declaring them in `for-loop` header section might be done for obviosity (some people say, that *those variables are definately used in this cycle*). Also it is shorter.

**NOTE:** You may use `,` for every header section of `for`-loop too.

---

***UPDv1:***

[`for`](http://php.net/for)-loop declaration:

```
for(initialization_section; condition_section; post_execution_section){
    // actions
}
```

Each of sections might contain **expression**, but can not contain other control structures.

**1) initialization_section:**

Should contain expressions to execute before loop starts.
If there is more than one separate expression, they should be separated by comma `,`.

Executes *before any* of `for`-loop iterations.

```
for($i = 0, $j = 1; $i < 10; $i++){
    echo "{$i} + {$j} = ", $i + $j, PHP_EOL;
}
```

Result:

```
0 + 1 = 1
1 + 1 = 2
2 + 1 = 3
3 + 1 = 4
4 + 1 = 5
5 + 1 = 6
6 + 1 = 7
7 + 1 = 8
8 + 1 = 9
9 + 1 = 10
```

**2) condition_section:**

Should contain expressions to check if loop continues or stops. If there is more than one separate action, they should be separated by comma `,`.

Executes *before every* `for`-loop iteration.

```
for($i = 1, $j = 0; $i++, $j < 10; $j++){
    echo "{$i} + {$j} = ", $i + $j, PHP_EOL;
}
```

Result:

```
2 + 0 = 2
3 + 1 = 4
4 + 2 = 6
5 + 3 = 8
6 + 4 = 10
7 + 5 = 12
8 + 6 = 14
9 + 7 = 16
10 + 8 = 18
11 + 9 = 20
```

Comma in this section of `for`-loop causes ignore of all previous expressions of this section, except the last one (as @**icktoofay** mentioned).

```
for($i = 0, $j = 1; $i < 1, $j < 5; $i++, $j++){
    echo "{$i} + {$j} = ", $i + $j, PHP_EOL;
}
```

Result:

```
0 + 1 = 1
1 + 2 = 3
2 + 3 = 5
3 + 4 = 7
```

Regardless of `$i < 1` is `false` for the second iteration. It might be used as default pre-execution statement.

**3) post_execution_section:**

Should contain expressions to execute after loop body actions are performed. If there is more than one separate action, they should be separated by comma `,`.

Executes *after every* `for`-loop iteration.

```
for($i = 0; $i < 10; $i++, $i *= 2){
    echo $i, PHP_EOL;
}
```

Result:

```
0
2
6
```

Also, each of `for`-loop sections might be empty (do nothing) with preserve of semicolon `;` separators:

```
for(;;){
    // infinite loop
}
```

Comment: `,` can even be used in the condition section, although you'll rarely find that in real code.

Comment: @icktoofay `,` there commonly replaced by `&&`. Yes, you are right.

Comment: `,` does a completely different thing than `&&`; they are not interchangeable. `,` does something that you rarely want: it evaluates the first operand, discards the result, and evaluates the latter operand. When you only care about the result, as in a condition, it is rarely useful. It is only useful when used for its side effect, as in an assignment. When there is no side effect as in a pure expression used for a condition, `,` is rarely used: I have only seen it used for obfuscation. Nonetheless, it can be used, and is not interchangeable with `&&`.

Comment: @icktoofay it should be mentioned. Never knew that. Thanks. I'll update answer soon.

Comment: Thank you for the very thorough answer!

Answer (score 4):

A comma in the first section of the loop just separates variable declarations.

Essentially it is just declaring  two variables `$j=0` and `$n2=sizeof($quotes[$i]['methods'])`, but in the loop constructor instead of before the loop constructor.